# Vector-valued weak analytic functions are strong analytic

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to prove: if a function $f: G\to V$, where $V$ is a complex Banach space and $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is an open subset, is *weakly analytic*, then it is *strong analytic*.  I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1672871/416552) and also read through Rudin's Thm 3.31. But the proof seems too complicated. I wonder whether the following direct estimate also works?

Let $z\in G$ and $\Delta_r(z):=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: 0\leq |w-z|<r\}$ such that $\overline{\Delta_{2r}(z)}\subset G$. Suppose $0< |h|<r$. On the boundary circle $\Gamma_{z,2r}:=\partial \Delta_{2r}(z)$, for every cts linear functional $x^*\in V^*$, we can apply $\mathbb{C}$-valued Cauchy Integral Formula,
\begin{align*}
x^*\left(\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}\right)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{(x^{*}\circ f)(\lambda)-(x^{*}\circ f)(z)}{(\lambda-z-h)(\lambda-z)}}d\lambda\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{(x^{*}\circ f)(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z-h)(\lambda-z)}}d\lambda-\frac{(x^{*}\circ f)(z)}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{d\lambda}{(\lambda-z-h)(\lambda-z)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{(x^{*}\circ f)(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z-h)(\lambda-z)}}d\lambda-0\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{(x^{*}\circ f)(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda+\frac{h}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{(x^{*}\circ f)(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z-h)(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda\\
&=x^*\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{f(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda\right)+\frac{h}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{(x^{*}\circ f)(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z-h)(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda.
\end{align*}
So, if denoting $M_{f, \Gamma}:=\sup\|f(\Gamma)\|$, we have the following estimate
$$\left|x^*\left(\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}- \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{f(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda\right)\right|\leq |h|  \|x^*\|\frac{M_{f, \Gamma}}{2r^2}$$

But now the upper bound depends on the functional norm $\|x^*\|$. Can we still conclude, using Hahn-Banach Thm, that
$$\left\|\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}- \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{f(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda\right\|_V\to 0, \text{ when } h\to 0?$$

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

It seems we can make that conclusion, by the canonical embedding to the bidual, $\Phi: V \to V^{**}$ and equality of norm $\|\Phi(x)\|_{V^{**}}=\|x\|_V$. With that, the above estimate is, for every $x^*\in V^*$,
$$\left|\Phi\left(\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}- \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{f(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda\right)(x^*)\right|\leq  |h|  \|x^*\|\frac{M_{f, \Gamma}}{2r^2}.$$
Hence, if letting
$$\xi(z,r,h):=\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}- \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{f(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda,$$
as $h\to 0$,
$$\left\|\xi\right\|_V=\left\|\Phi(\xi)(x^*)\right\|_{V^{**}}=\sup_{x^*\in V^*} \frac{|\Phi(\xi)(x^*)|}{\|x^*\|}\leq |h|\frac{M_{f, \Gamma}}{2r^2}\to 0.$$
That is
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{z,2r}}{\frac{f(\lambda)}{(\lambda-z)^2}}d\lambda \in V.$$

Correct?

Comment: This seems indeed correct. In fact this is quite nice. By the way I took the liberty of removing the functional-calculus tag as functional calculus is about applying a function to an operator, for example to make sense of $A^2$ or $e^{tA}$ and the likes for unbounded operators which won't benefit from classical definitions (e.g. with norm-convergent power series for holomorphic functions and bounded operators). But it's not the end of the world to have put that tag on here, don't worry. Have a great day.